# Word 2010: Level 10 heading and beyond

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My document requires that more than 9 heading levels be used.  The problem is that all headings need to generate into the TOC and the page numbers need to include the heading level.   Is there a way to generate page numbers to include custom-made heading 10 and above?  Thanks!

Comment: You can create your own levels using listnum fields

Comment: Thank you!  I will do some research on that.  Another option I thought of was to add custom text in the page numbering field.  I can easily add just before the { PAGE } code, but it doesn't generate into the TOC.  Any ideas on that one?  I tried { "Custom Text-" { PAGE } }, but that didn't work.  TY!

Comment: @Robin, You may find the answer to that one at: http://superuser.com/questions/448284/formatting-page-numbers-in-table-of-contents-to-include-text/448438#448438

Comment: @Adam.  Thanks!  I read that and tried it; it works.  Working with a bunch of engineers (no offense), and it may be difficult to 'train' them.  Seems I'm always trying to get the software to do something it's not intended to!  LOL!